# How to capture bteq command result to variable without using flat file

Tags: unix, teradata

Environment : Unix, DB : Teradata 
Using `bteq command`, I want to capture result of a select statement in a variable

Eg: `select count(*) from mytable`
Store the result in variable so I can do an if else on the variable later.

I do not want to store a single variable in a file and then read it.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using flat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't need a file, just an *output filter*:

```
query_td () {
bteq << EOBTQ |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.LOGON dsn/user_id,password;
SELECT   '>'||'Dummy test';

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOBTQ
}


$ var=$(query_td)
$ echo $var
Dummy test
```

**Explanation**

The trick is to add a additional char `>` **at the beginning** of the select statement:

`SELECT   '>'||'Dummy test';`

`grep '^>'` filters the output coming out from `bteq` [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) document so we just keep the result of the `query`.

The last move is to *clean up* the char `>` added to filter with `sed -e "s/^>//"`.

Comment: Really quick and easy way to do this. Thanks. I just would like to understand how this works? |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" sends the output of the bteq where?

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot for explaining. Cheers!!1

Answer (score 0):

Place your select query in a file and run the following shell script. You should have the output in log.txt from which you can parse the query output.

shell.sh:

```
bteq << EOF >> log.txt
.logon dsn/user_id,password;
.set width 2000;
.run FILE = /home/user_id/query.txt;
.logoff;
.quit;
EOF
```

Comment: Where will it store the result?
(I am new to Unix)

Comment: I am trying this one command is executing but not creating log file

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following commands in the BTEQ Manual:

- **WIDTH** - Set the width in characters for your EXPORT
- **FORMAT**
- **TITLEDASHES** - Column dashes underneath column headers if you return them
- **EXPORT** - Output of just the SELECT query is written to flat file.

With the correct settings you should be able to capture just the value returned by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;` and then later in your shell script parse the flat file to use the value. Furthermore you could return multiple columns in a manner which could be fed into AWK and read as columns fairly easily.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can do it without using flat file?